# how to expire php session if user is inactive for 15 mins

Tags: php, session

i have created one project in PHP, into which i am managing sessions.

I am creating session in my config.php file by writing following line of code.

```
session_start();
```

and to destroy this session, in logout.php file i have write following line.

```
session_destroy();
```

and i have not mention any code for session in any other project file, but the problem is session is active untill i call logout.php,

what i want is session should expire if user is inactive for 15 minutes.

can anyone help me for this, i am new to PHP, please give some example code or link to achieve this..

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/686406-php-session-time-limit

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002975/set-expire-time-for-a-session

Comment: HINT: try search on StackOverflow before posting a question

Comment: oh, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770150/php-make-session-expire-after-x-minutes

Comment: ok tekknolagi, thanks for the quick help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call below function in your header file, so that whenever user does any activity at that time page gets refreshed and check whether session time outs or not.

```
function auto_logout($field)
{
    $t = time();
    $t0 = $_SESSION[$field];
    $diff = $t - $t0;
    if ($diff > 1500 || !isset($t0))
    {          
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[$field] = time();
    }
}
```

Use something like this in header

```
    if(auto_logout("user_time"))
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        location("login.php");          
        exit;
    }
```

User_time is the session name. I hope this answer will help you. What actually this code does is : "Checks whether diff is greater than 1500 seconds or not. If not then set new session time." You can change time diff(1500) according to your requirement.

Comment: just one question kamal, how do i create a session with name `user_time`, becoz i used to simply write `session_start()`

Comment: You need to write $_SESSION['name'];

Answer (score 4):

try

```
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',54000);  
  ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
  ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
```

use this before calling session_start()

Comment: if i write this 3 lines in my `config.php` file before `session_start()` will it work for my entire project? as `config.php` is included in all other project files

Comment: ok, following is the code in my `config.php` see will it work? `<?php
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',54000);  
  ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
  ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
  session_start();
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root');
  mysql_select_db('dbname',$link) or die("Not Able To Connect To DataBase");

?>`

Comment: i have write following code in config.php for testing purpose `<?php
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',3600);  
  ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
  ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
  session_start();
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root');
  mysql_select_db('dbname',$link) or die("Not Able To Connect To DataBase");

?>` which means session should expire in `1 min`, but i didn't

Comment: I also tried this solution -- didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

Store `time()` in the `$time` variable. create variable called `$setTime` and set the time you want user to timeout.

After that check the condition that if `$_SESSION['setTime']` is empty OR not set then store the timeout value into the session, otherwise when the page will refresh the new value will be assigned to the `$_SESSION['setTime']`.

```
$time = time ();
    $setTime = time () + 60;
    if (empty ( $_SESSION ['setTime'] ) || !isset ( $_SESSION ['setTime'] )) {
        $_SESSION ['setTime'] = $setTime;
    }
```

After that check that current time is more than equal to the stored time. and if it is unset the session. destroy the session as well.

```
if (time () >= ( int ) $_SESSION ['setTime']) {
   session_unset ();
   session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
# Session Logout after in activity 
function sessionX(){ 
    $logLength = 1800; # time in seconds :: 1800 = 30 minutes 
    $ctime = strtotime("now"); # Create a time from a string 
    # If no session time is created, create one 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionX'])){  
        # create session time 
        $_SESSION['sessionX'] = $ctime;  
    }else{ 
        # Check if they have exceded the time limit of inactivity 
        if(((strtotime("now") - $_SESSION['sessionX']) > $logLength) && isLogged()){ 
            # If exceded the time, log the user out 
            logOut(); 
            # Redirect to login page to log back in 
            header("Location: /login.php"); 
            exit; 
        }else{ 
            # If they have not exceded the time limit of inactivity, keep them logged in 
            $_SESSION['sessionX'] = $ctime; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But remember Function sessionX() MUST come after session_start()

See details [here](http://phpsnips.com/snippet.php?id=39)

Comment: if i write this code in my `config.php` file only, will this work for entire project, as my `config.php` is included in all other project files ??

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an answered question but I just wanted to share my experience and since I feel like this is a more easy approach. I'm not sure if this is the best way but here goes. What I did was:

1. I set a PHP Session ($_SESSION['timeout']) to current time (time()) when the user logged in.
2. Wrote the following function to validate whether the user is active.

> function sessionTimeOut() {
>
> // This function is adding 900 seconds (15 Minutes, which is the amount of time you want the user to // be inactive to automatically logout) to the previously registered time when the user was last active. // Then, its checking whether the current time is greater than the amount of time you want the user to // stay logged in without timing out (which is 15 minutes). If it's greater, then you are redirected to the // login page where you can initiate a logout function with http://www.yourwebpage/login.php?status=timeout on the URL.
>
> if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 900 > time()) {
>
> ```
>   // User Active so reset time session.
>   $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
> ```
>
> } else {
>
> ```
>   // session timed out then redirect to login page
>   header('Location:http://'. $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . '/login.php?status=timeout');
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Lastly: Call sessionTimeOut(); function in the header after checking if user is logged in. This allows the function to be called every time the user refreshes or navigates to a new page. Thus, it works perfectly (atleast in my case), fulfils my purpose, so I thought I'd just share it with you guys.

Answer (score -1):

This is in continuation to what Kamal posted. I tried same code but made it work it by modifying it as below:

```
/* code */
function fnlogout($field)
{
    $t = time();
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$field]))
        $_SESSION[$field] = time();
    $t0 = $_SESSION[$field];
    $diff = $t - $t0;
    if ($diff > 60)
    {        
        return true;
    }enter code here
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
function fnheader()
{
    if(fnlogout("user_time"))
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("location:index.php?action=expired");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Yes, Kamal is right about the location of code inserts. One part as function and other in header of each file or common header function.