# How to expire PHP session after 10 minutes of inactivity?

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php and I am working on a web application where the requirement is that the user should be automatically logged out and returned to the login screen if there is no user activity for 10 minutes. How can I achieve this using either php or javascript?

I am currently just using session_start() in my header page.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',54000);  
 ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
 ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
```

use this before calling `session_start()`

**Or Also Try by this**

Store time() in the $time variable.
After that check the condition that if $_SESSION['setTime'] is empty OR not set then store the timeout value into the session, otherwise when the page will refresh the new value will be assigned to the $_SESSION['setTime'].

```
    $time = time ();
        $setTime = time () + 60;
        if (empty ( $_SESSION ['setTime'] ) || !isset ( $_SESSION ['setTime'] )) {
            $_SESSION ['setTime'] = $setTime;
   }
```

After that check that current time is more than equal to the stored time. and if it is unset the session. destroy the session as well.

```
if (time () >= ( int ) $_SESSION ['setTime']) {
   session_unset ();
   session_destroy ();
}
```

AS per [how to expire php session if user is inactive for 15 mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124560/how-to-expire-php-session-if-user-is-inactive-for-15-mins)

Comment: Making the GC run on every single request is not a good idea, that can easily affect performance.

Comment: Also this can be change in `php.ini` globally